# Locate maximum cell within a radius r around a central cell

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have a raster. Is it possible to find the location of a maximum cell within a defined radius'r' around a central cell.

Comment: What would this even look like? Exactly what value would be assigned to the resulting raster? In R, and probably Python as well, one could take each focal matrix and return rasters representing distance and direction to the maximum cell but, this is not possible with off the shelf ArcGIS. The only viable approach would be to convert your data to points but, this is not feasible for large rasters.

Comment: Jeffrey: To elaborate more on what I am trying to do. I am using the 'range' statistics type within the 'focal statistics' tool. For each central pixel ArcGIS calculates the difference between the highest and lowest values in the defined neighborhood area and assigns it to the central pixel. But it does not give the actual location of the max/min pixels as an output. What I am now looking for is a way to locate the highest and lowest pixels within that defined neighborhood areas.

Comment: The purpose is to find upper and lower reservoir locations for potential pumped storage hydropower sites in a large area. My input is a Digital Elevation Model.

Answer (score 1):

Another Spatial Analyst tool I would try is Focal Statistics. It uses a defined neighborhood around each cell (in either cells or map units) to calculate statistics. Maximum is one of the options under Statistics Type.

[image]